# why does create index with SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; and SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0; take a lot of time?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

i am adding index to a very large table , around 25 M records and 60 GB of data.
i am using MYSQL version 5.6 InnoDB , my statement is :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
ALTER TABLE `my_table`
ADD   KEY `my_idx` (`site_id`,`name`);
```

and i am running it like this :

```
mysql --host=**.database.azure.com -u *** -p*** my_db < my_file.sql
```

but it take around 1 hour , the same time as without this statement , what am i missing ?

Comment: Does the time matter?  According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html , it "permits concurrent DML".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) and [`SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_unique_checks) are meant for speeding up imports (typically `INSERT` statements) into tables where foreign keys and unique indexes already exist. They are not meant to speed up the creation of indexes.

Comment: are you sure that this flags will not affect altering table with a lot of data adding keys and constraint ?

Comment: I've done some brief testing. With `UNIQUE_CHECKS=0` you'll get an error (duplicate entry) if you try to add a unique constraint on a column where the data isn't unique. With `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` you will not get an error if you add a foreign key constraint on a column that points to non-existent rows in the parent table. So maybe `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` can actually speed up foreign key/index creation?